# I'm unable to load @apollo/client on a React Native Expo app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to load @apollo/client on a React Native Expo app.

And I get this error:

> While trying to resolve module `@apollo/client` from file `/Users/andrepena/git/anglio-mobile-rn/screens/dictionary/index.tsx`, the package `/Users/andrepena/git/anglio-mobile-rn/node_modules/@apollo/client/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/andrepena/git/anglio-mobile-rn/node_modules/@apollo/client/main.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist

Then I searched Stackoverflow and someone said I should add this to my `metro.config.json`

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");
const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");
module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

But now, all imports from @apollo/client simply return `undefined`.

Example:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
console.log(ApolloClient); // undefined
console.log(InMemoryCache); // undefined
```

In fact, `@apollo/client` is exporting this object:

```
Object {
  "default": 17,
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71635719/how-to-run-apollo-client-in-expo

Comment: You said metro.config.json, shouldn't it be metro.config.js?

Answer (score 0):

This `metro.config.js` worked for me: (remember to install `@expo/metro-config`)

const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');

```
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname, {
    // Initialize in exotic mode.
    // If you want to preserve `react-native` resolver main field, and omit cjs support, then leave this undefined
    // and skip setting the `EXPO_USE_EXOTIC` environment variable.
    mode: 'exotic',
});

module.exports = config;
```

The exotic thing makes Metro to be able to find the weird cjs module that @apollo/client exports